# Redux: State does not update reactively while using nested properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple container for a sidebar. It looks as follows:

```
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar';
import Actions from '../actions/sidebar';

export default connect(function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    sidebar: state.sidebar,
    device: state.device
  }
}, function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    sidebar: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
  }
}, function mergeProps(state, dispatch) {
  return { state, dispatch }
})(Sidebar);
```

When I log my `this.props` on my component instance, it appears to have worked completely as intended. However, when I try to reference a nested property within `this.props.state`, it does not appear to update reactively, despite the state changing (completely confirmed that the state changes).

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      state:   { sidebar: { open } },
      actions: { sidebar: { toggle } }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Drawer open={open}>
        // ....
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
```

When I create a flat structure out of the state, it appears to work exactly as intended, but when I nest the `open` boolean like in the above example, it never updates, despite the state appropriately updating.

How do I use nested state properties in my connect function with react and redux?

Comment: Why are you referring to `sidebar` directly as opposed to using `this.props.sidebar`?

Comment: In the same vein of what himmel is asking, did you forget `= this` at the end of your destructuring at the beginning of the render?

Comment: oops sorry, just edited it. Forgot the `= this.props` (rewrote it by hand to reduce it down to the basic component)

Comment: The problem could lie in your reducer. Are you mutating the state.sidebar object or are you returning a new object with the updated values?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that properly updates the `open` variable?

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering

Comment: I think that FAQ did it -- the change seemed pretty innocuous. When I changed `Object.assign(state, { something: something })` in my reducer to `Object.assign({}, state, { something: something })` it worked perfectly. Want to put it in an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: As the author of that FAQ, seeing this makes me _very_ happy :)

Comment: Haha, thanks it's okay, why don't you copy your "broken" code along with the fix in an answer and accept it. :)  I think my comment was good enough for this.  Great to see @markerikson get some credit too! :)